# Postgres join tables array JSONB column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a field with the this data in bonuses.rules:

```
[
  {
    "rule":{
        "providers":[
          "11",
          "12",
        ]
    }
}
```

]

The content of "rule-> providers" is array. there is an example above.

I want to join these providers with provider_games.provider_id.

this is my query, but the blank result is returned.

```
SELECT bonuses.rules, bonuses.bonus_id, provider_games.provider_id
FROM bonuses
          inner JOIN provider_games ON bonuses.rules -> '[{"rule": {"providers"}}]'
     @> json_build_array (json_build_object ('provider_id', provider_games.provider_id)) :: jsonb
```

provider_games table:

```
create table provider_games
(
    provider_game_id bigserial not null
        constraint provider_games_pkey
            primary key
);

alter table provider_games owner to defaultdb;
```

bonuses table:

```
create table bonuses
(
    bonus_id bigserial not null
        constraint bonuses_pkey
            primary key,
    rules jsonb
);

alter table bonuses owner to defaultdb;
```

Comment: `bonuses.rules -> '[{"rule": {"providers"}}]'` looks wrong.

Comment: How should multiple rule objects in that array be handled?

Comment: Thanks your reply. I want the combination of providers_id and provider_games.providers_id in bonuses.rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `JOIN`ing on a `@>`, I would recommend to do joins against [lateral subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) that unnest the json:

```
SELECT bonuses.rules, bonuses.bonus_id, provider_games.provider_game_id
FROM bonuses,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) rules(obj),
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'providers') rule_provider(id)
INNER JOIN provider_games ON provider_games.provider_game_id = rule_provider.id::bigint;
```

<sup>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=deaef4769e59f5b396f729ae25c55e0c))</sup>